# Extrair informação do PDF através da posição utilizando PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Tem como extrair a informação de acordo com a posição no PDF (coordenada x,y) em PHP? Ja vi que é possível fazer isso em C# utilizando a classe PdfReader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar os seguintes:

[PDFParser](http://www.pdfparser.org/)

[PDF Text Extractor](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/31030.html) - (requer cadastro)

ou [esta classe](http://pastebin.com/dvwySU1a) - (ultima atualização 2014)

Comment: Eu ja utilizei estas funções... Elas pegam tudo que possui no PDF.. Eu gostaria de pegar somente de uma área do PDF, ou seja, passar as coordenadas e somente pegar o texto daquela área selecionada!

Comment: Se essa area que voce quer pegar com cordenadas é sempre fixa então é uma propriedade do documento como `CreationDate` ou `Page` certo?

Comment: É o seguinte... Vão ser vários tipos de PDF's, para cada modelo eu vou criar uma "máscara" para fazer a extração das informações e essa informações não são como o CreationDate ou Page.

Comment: use o PDFParser e com o o texto gerado use a função `strripos` do PHP para encontrar a palavra ou trecho que você quer, tente manipular desse jeito.

Comment: Se não houver outra forma vou fazer assim... Estou tentando fazer isso para que não pegue informações irrelevantes, pois os PDF's que irei manipular nem sempre o OCR compreende todas as letras. O meu objetivo e extrair os dados do PDF e fazer a inserção no banco de dados para que a inserção de documentos no meu sistema GED fique automática. Agradeço a sua ajuda e a sua boa vontade!

Comment: @JordanBragon Conseguiu fazer funcionar desta maneira? Tehno a necessidade de algo parecido.

Comment: @JordanBragon conseguiu resolver? Estou precisando de algo semelhante.

Comment: @WillianCoqueiro não consegui!